# Show that the closure of a connected set is also connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

I'm doing exercise II.4.5 in textbook Analysis I by Amann.

Could you please verify if my attempt contains logical mistakes/gaps! Thank you so much!

> [image]

**My attempt:**

> **Lemma:** $f:X \to Y$ is continuous iff $f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}$ for all $A \subseteq X$.

Assume that $f : \overline{A} \rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is continuous, then the restriction $f \restriction A : A \rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is continuous because $A \subseteq \overline{A}$.  Because $A$ is connected, then $f \restriction A$ is not surjective. WLOG, we assume $f[A] = \{0\}$. Since $\{0\}$ is both closed and open in $\{0,1\}$, $\overline{f[A]} = \overline{\{0\}} = \{0\}$. By **Lemma**,  $f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}= \{0\}$, so $f$ is not surjective. Hence $\overline{A}$ is connected.

Comment: (1) "wlog we assume $f[A] = \{0\}$". you can have $A = \emptyset$ and thus $f[A] = \emptyset$. Of course, if $A = \emptyset$, then $\overline{A} = \emptyset$, but you should still mention this. (2) "the restriction $f | A : A \to \{0,1\}$ is continuous because $A \subseteq \overline{A}$" is worded a bit weirdly. The fact that $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ implies that the restriction is well-defined. And then there's the general fact that restrictions of continuous functions are continuous. (3) Maybe add a Lemma that $B$ is connected iff every continuous $f: B \to \{0,1\}$ is not surjective?

Comment: The rest is good though

Comment: Thank you so much @mathworker21 ^o^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it from  scratch? Towards a contradiction, suppose $\overline A=C\cup D$ for some non-empty sets $C,D$ open in $\overline A$.  Since $A$ is connected, we may assume without loss of generality, that $A\subseteq C$. Then, $\overline A\subseteq \overline C.$ But $\overline C\cap D=\emptyset$ (why?) and so $\overline A\cap D=\emptyset$. Thus, we have shown that $D$ is empty, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Please confirm if my understanding of your proof is correct! 1. Either $A\subseteq C$ or $A\subseteq D$. If not $\emptyset \neq (A \cap C)$ is open in $A$ and $\emptyset \neq (A \cap D)$ is open in $A$. So $A$ is not connected, which is a contradiction. 2. $\overline C\cap D=\emptyset$. If not there is $a \in\overline C\cap D$. Since $D$ is open, there is an open ball $\mathbb B(a,r) \subseteq D$. Moreover, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $C$ such that $x_n \to a$. As such, there is some $x_N \in \mathbb B(a,r)$. So $x_N \in (C \cap D)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Akira your proofs are fine. Note, however, that 2. is true for any topological space so you might try to prove it in the general case.

Comment: how is this an answer? the question was whether akira's proof was correct

Comment: @mathworker21   Fair point, but I think it's legitimate to offer simpler proofs, right? When I post questions, I always appreciate the offer of different proofs, even if I am only asking for verification of my own. That way, I learn more, which after all, is the idea here. OK?

Comment: @Matematleta yea, I agree, this "answer" would be a great comment!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simpler put: if $A$ is connected, $f[A] \neq \{0,1\}$ and $f[A]$ is closed in $\{0,1\}$, as all its subsets are closed.

So $$f[A] \subseteq f[\overline{A}] \subseteq \overline{f[A]}  =f[A]$$ so that $f[\overline{A}] =f[A] \neq \{0,1\}$ as well.